# directory is not created using phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, directory, cordova-plugin-file

Having problem with creating directories,here's my code:

```
var d = new Date(); 
var n = d.getTime(); 
var newFileName = n + ".jpg"; 
var myFolderApp = "myFolder"; 
var newFile=myFolderApp+"/"+newFileName; 

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) { 
alert('root is :'+fileSys.root.name) 

fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder",{create:true, exclusive: false}, 
function(directory) 
{ 
alert('direcrory name :'+directory.name) 
fileSystem.copyTo(directory, newFileName,function(fileSystem) 
{ 

alert('file sved!') 

      }, resOnError); 
   }, 
     resOnError); 
 }, 
  resOnError); 

 function resOnError(error) { 
    alert('Error at resOnError :'+error.code+' ,message :'+eror.message); 
    }
```

Also added both permissions for read and write.

1. this is the plugin "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file" used.
2. calling this function via another function,not using device ready event.

3.**directory is not created and code execute with no error.**

Thanks

---

HERE's Code
        var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

```
(function(){
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
})();


function onDeviceReady() 
{
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;   
}

function save()
{
     alert(imageForCategory)
               window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageForCategory,resolveOnSuccess,resOnError);
}

function onFail(message) 
{
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
function getPhoto(source) 
{
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality:     100,destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,sourceType: source });
}
var imageForCategory="";
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) 
{
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
      imageForCategory=largeImage.src;
}

function resOnError(error) {
    alert('Error at resOnError :'+error.code+' ,message :'+error.message);
}
function resolveOnSuccess(fileSystem)
{

    alert('on resolve success called');
    var d = new Date(); 
    var n = d.getTime();
    var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "myFolder";
    var newFile = myFolderApp + "/" + newFileName;

   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function    (fileSys)     {
        alert('root is :' + fileSys.root.name);

        fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder", {create: true, exclusive:    false},
            function (directory) {
                alert('directory name :' + directory.name);
                directory.getFile(newFileName, {create: true}, function (file) {
                    alert("File created.");
                });
            }, resOnError);
    }, resOnError);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the device ready event? You have to, otherwise your code will not work.

Comment: now calling by deviceready evet ,still not creating directory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want to do. It seams that you want to copy a file, but you don't tell something about the source.

If you want to create a file, then use this code:

```
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "myFolder";
    var newFile = myFolderApp + "/" + newFileName;

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSys) {
        alert('root is :' + fileSys.root.name);

        fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder", {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function (directory) {
                alert('directory name :' + directory.name);
                directory.getFile(newFileName, {create: true}, function (file) {
                    alert("File created.");
                });
            }, resOnError);
    }, resOnError);

    function resOnError(error) {
        alert('Error at resOnError :' + error.code + ' ,message :' + eror.message);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Joerg,
What i am trying to do is to save an image into 'myfolder' name directory and it is not creating nor copying image into my directory and the code executes without error.
thanks

Comment: My above code is working for creating a directory. BUT, where is your file, that you want to copy, that is the important question.

Comment: still not able to create directory.
cordova version-5.4.1

Comment: I don't have more infos, sorry. You wrote in your post, that you gave some permissions. What does that mean, because in a standard configuration there is no need to do that. On the other hand: have you tried to use an other device or simulator like genymotion?

Comment: yes permissions are auto created when i install plugin of file and file-transfer.
Also have tried on different devices and in simulator but still code doesn't create directory.